# Neo4J: Installation ERROR

Tags: neo4j, installation, command, prompt

I'm getting an error with Neo4j when it comes to runnning the installation on my pc. I've gone to the terminal and tried to run the Neo4jInstaller.bat.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR! You are using an unsupported version of Java, please use Oracle HotSpot 1.7. 
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

Access is denied.

[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

I have tried look through other tutorials but I can't find anything that helps!

Comment: Have you tried a different version of java than what you have installed? Judging by the error message that is where I would start. Neo4j requirements are listed here.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-requirements.html

Comment: Are you trying to start it as a service? If so, did you just try starting it by double clicking on the executable (or bat file??) in the bin directory? It launches a dialogue with start/stop buttons and a text box for the fully qualified database path.

Comment: How did you install Neo4j?

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly? I got a similar error and addressed it by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the folder of JDK. I am using Windows.

Comment: I just got this error too. I got it when I installed Neo4J from the zip (the normal installer requires a GUI to be open all the time which is... meh). I'm going to double check the java home now though.

Comment: Don't know about the OP, but I'm getting this error with the following java version info: java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)